# How to make these continuous dates to make it weekly? In python

Tags: python, datetime

Here I take this code from the internet and i had a confusion in this. It is a impressive code which prints dates continuously but i want it **Weekly** from the starting date...

The code is

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date

dt = datetime.datetime.now()

d = dt.day
m = dt.month
y = dt.year

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(y, m, d)
end_dt = date(y, 7, 1)
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    print(dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

**The output now is **
23-06-2021
24-06-2021
25-06-2021
26-06-2021
27-06-2021
28-06-2021
29-06-2021
30-06-2021
01-07-2021

**But i want the output to be like..**
23-06-2021
30-06-2021
7-07-2021.......

Comment: you could make 7-day steps; `range(0, int((date2 - date1).days)+1, 7)`, see also [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: `from datetime import date, timedelta ; start = date.today() ; end = date.today() + timedelta(days=100) ; print(*(start + timedelta(weeks=i) for i in range((end - start).days // 7)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a time interval parameter that allows you to control the number of days between each returned date. Set it to "7" for weeks. It works by adding an additional "step" parameter to the range() function that creates the range of days to be added in each timedelta in your generator function.

```
def daterange(date1, date2, day_interval):
    date_range = int((date2 - date1).days)
    for n in range(0, date_range+1, day_interval):
        yield date1 + timedelta(days=n)

for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt, 7):
    print(dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

edit: I see that sophros beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

The key change is to amend the `range` iterator so that it returns 7-day intervals:

```
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(0,int((date2 - date1).days)+1,7):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)
```

Please note a need to use 3-argument version of `range(start, stop, interval)`.

For `end_dt = date(y, 10, 1)`:

```
23-06-2021
30-06-2021
07-07-2021
14-07-2021
21-07-2021
28-07-2021
04-08-2021
11-08-2021
18-08-2021
25-08-2021
```